# Mac Txt File With Curly Quotes In Notepad++ On Windows

Tags: notepad++

I'm so tired of changing curly quotes to real quotes. Some people that work with me use Mac OS X and when they send me .txt files they ALWAYS have curly quotes

I open them on Windows with notepad++ but I tried OpenOffice too and they are still there

Is there an option in notepad++ to AutoCorrect them?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can record a simple macro in Notepad++

Record a macro of a manual change using a simple find and replace all.

Then assign the macro to a keyboard shortcut and run it whenever you want to.

Comment: Glad I can help.